# how can i make my silverlight control load faster

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I cached my control ,but there is still a long pause.  What could I do to make this go even quicker?

What are some general tips for improving silverlight application loading speed.

Comment: It will be necessary for you to share more details about your control. Most controls will load pretty fast, so without knowing what is causing your control to load so slowly it is hard to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Silverlight toolkit themes, remove them from the project and measure the improvement. In our case, we noticed a major improvement in terms of load time performance just doing that. I subsequently copied some of the styles to our own resource files rather than refering the theming toolkit. Apologies if this does not apply in your case.